# Estimating Lorentzian inner product

Tags: inner-products, hyperbolic-geometry, bilinear-form, semi-riemannian-geometry

Let $\mathbb{L}^{n+1}$ be the Lorentz space, that is, the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ equipped with the nondegenerate bilinear form

$$ \langle x, y\rangle = x_1 y_1 + \cdots + x_n y_n - x_{n+1} y_{n+1}. $$

A model for the hyperbolic space is given by the set 
$$\mathbb{H}^n = \{ x \in \mathbb{L}^{n+1} : \langle x, x \rangle = -1, \; x_{n+1} > 0\} $$
with the metric induced by $\mathbb{L}^{n+1}$ (It can be shown that the restriction of this bilinear form to the tangent spaces of $\mathbb{H}^n$ is positive definite).

Let $p_0 = (0, \dots, 0, 1) \in \mathbb{H}^n$. My question is: if $v \in T_p \mathbb{H}^n \subseteq \mathbb{L}^{n+1}$ is a tangent vector at $p \in \mathbb{H}^n$ such that $\langle v, v\rangle = 1$, can we say that $\langle v, p_0 \rangle \leq 1$?
I'm a bit confused because Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is no longer valid.

Comment: How is $p$ in "$\nu\in T_p\Bbb{H}^n\subseteq\Bbb{L}^{n+1}$" quantified? Did you mean "$T_{p_0}\Bbb{H}^n$", or is $p$ an arbitrary element of $\Bbb{H}^n$?

Comment: Yes, I meant $p \in \mathbb{H}^n$, thanks.

Comment: It seems that $p$ is a red herring. For any space-like vector $v \in \mathbb{L}^{n+1}$ there exists $p \in \mathbb{H}^n$ such that $v \in T_p \mathbb{H}^n$. So your question is really just a question about space-like vectors in $\mathbb{L}^{n+1}$. A space like vector that is nearly parallel to the light cone should provide a counterexample.